# A programming technique for android web scraping application

Tags: java, android, web-scraping

I am building an android application , that will plot a list of addresses on a google map.
The list of addresses are on a website. . What would be the best way to scrape these addresses from the website, and then store them into my android application sqlite database.

This is the website
http://itica.ie/chipper_directory

What would be the best way to go about programming for this website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an HTML parser. [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is good, and easy to use.